# Reducing File size

Tags: file-size

I am using `XeTeX+bibTeX` to compile my LaTeX file. I have around 34 pages, which includes over 20 high Quality images (Large size which are rescaled) and I am using `a5paper` for the `book` document class. also I'm using `figure`, `TiKz` and `lslisting`. after compiling the document I now have a PDF of size 250MB !

could someone please give me a better compiling option (I'm using TeX Maker) or what to do to reduce size(best practices)?

I forgot to mention that when having the `draft` option the file size becomes 100MB

Thanks !

Comment: Remove all figures, check the size, remove the tikz and check the size, remove the listings and check the size, and so on. Maybe you can find the guilty one that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first shot you could rescale your images, so that you can include them without much scaling in the Latex document. The difference of 250 MB might be an indication that the images eat up a lot of space.

What format are the images?

Comment: 10 are JPG, few others are PNG , 2 are PDFs

Comment: What I observed some time ago, is that when I compile Latex via dvi and ps to pdf, the ps file was 5 to 10 times the size of the pdf. I had a lot photos in the document. So pixel-based images can be real space eaters.

Comment: When I use matlab2tikz to create plots in tikz, I usually define a minimumPointsDistance to keep the tikz-file and thus the memory consumption during compilation small. You don't need millions of data points in a plot in a document. So, if you have reason to suspect your tikz graphics, you could compile them into standalone documents to check what size the results have.